# Android UnknownHostException : is there a way to set timeout?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

When I connect to my webservice to retreive data, the phone is sometimes getting disconnected, DNS messed up, etc. Then I get an `UnknownHostException` which is perfectly fine.

What I want to do is to set a timeout when looking for the hostName here:

```
 response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

I have already set :

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,timeoutConnection);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```

but they don't seem to apply for `HostLookUp`.  Is there any way to set the timeout at host lookup?

**Edit**
I just found that the user cannot modify the timeout of `nslookup` [in this post on the hc-dev mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-dev/201005.mbox/%3C29920365.3851273587582767.JavaMail.jira@thor%3E).

I will have to manually throw a timeout exception from a timer at that point.

Comment: Please give the Ip address in which your web service is running instead of domain name. I also faced the same problem. But my webservice runs on my machine locally. So while i am giving localhost its throws an exception. But its accept my ip address.

Answer (score 2):

First of all HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams() is depricated,
use this HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

when your parameters size greater than 2mb then server give time out responce.

Check your params size and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I find Volley (I would say replacement of AsyncTask) library is easier to use and also gives less bugs. If you use volley, it's easier to manage timeouts. However, regarding your question,

```
  response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

with this I supposed you are using AsyncTask. There is an option to `settimeout()` in httpconnection as well but that doesn't work properly due to it's problem with DNS. So try using `runnable()` and settime to it. I have used this approach in one of my project, way back when not using Volley yet.

Hope that would help.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use threading for network operations then you can give a timeout externally.I had used this method to solve problem where defining timeout was not working.

In this method post communication codes are written in a Handler. We can trigger this handler by sending message(we can also pass data through messages). Triggering statements are written in a count down timer and after the communication codes in thread.And necessary code is written in handler to disable anymore triggering(by assigning a new Empty handler to the object)So that only one of the triggering work.

If you like this logic and required more explanation. Please comment below

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :-

```
URLConnection connection = null;
connection =  address.openConnection();
post = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
post.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory()); 
post.setDoInput(true);
post.setDoOutput(true);

// Connecting to a server will fail with a SocketTimeoutException if the timeout     elapses before a connection is established
post.setConnectTimeout(Const.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_DELAY);
post.setRequestMethod("POST");  // throws ProtocolException


post.setRequestProperty("soapaction","");
post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
post.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +         Base64.encodeToString(strCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
            post.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",           String.valueOf(requestEnvelope.length()));
```

//Reading will fail with a SocketTimeoutException if the timeout elapses before data becomes available..
post.setReadTimeout(Const.READ_TIMEOUT_DELAY);

Answer (score 0):

For me the timeout wasn't used if we lost the connection (to test : shut down the WiFi). So I wrote a method that tries to download the file up to X times, waiting Y milliseconds between each try :

```
public static byte[] getByteArrayFromURL(String url, int maxTries, int intervalBetweenTries) throws IOException {

    try {

        return Utils.getByteArrayFromURL(url);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) { throw e; }
    catch(IOException e) {

        if(maxTries > 0) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(intervalBetweenTries);
                return getByteArrayFromURL(url, maxTries - 1, intervalBetweenTries);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                return getByteArrayFromURL(url, maxTries -1, intervalBetweenTries);
            }
        }
        else {

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method that download the file and throws the UnknownHostException :

```
public static byte[] getByteArrayFromURL(String urlString) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = null;
    try {

        in = new URL(urlString).openStream();
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n;

        while ((n = in.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            out.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try { in.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Now, if the file that you want to download doesn't exist, the method will fail immediately, else if an IOException is thrown (like the UnknownHostException), it will retry, up to "maxTries", waiting "intervalBetweenTries" between each try.

Of course, you must use this asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one , may be it will be helpful for you.

```
final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams()


HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1000)


HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000) 

HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams)

try
 {


 HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com")

  HttpResponse response = hc.execute(get)

  take your response now.
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like this:

```
/**
 * Check availability of web service
 * 
 * @param host Address of host
 * @param seconds Timeout in seconds
 * @return Availability of host
 */
public static boolean checkIfURLExists(String host, int seconds)
{
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn;
    try
    {
        httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(host).openConnection();

        // Set timeouts in milliseconds
        httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(seconds * 1000);
        httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(seconds * 1000);

        // Print HTTP status code/message for your information.
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + httpUrlConn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Response Message: "
                + httpUrlConn.getResponseMessage());

        return (httpUrlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: setConnectTimeout and setReadTimeout don't apply for DNS resolving runtime ... that is the problem

Answer (score -2):

You can send ping request to your server and set timeout for ping request. If true you have internet connection, if false do nothing. Code should look like this:

```
public static boolean connection() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String ipAddress = "94.103.35.164";
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

    if(inet.isReachable(1000)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can change your time out in this example. I set 1 second timeout.

Answer (score -3):

yes you can set the time out follow this steps

1. go to eclipse's window->preferences->Android->DDMS and increase ADB connection time out.

Comment: -1: weakwire is talking about a timeout in his app -- not in the ADB connection.